# Using instanceof operator

Tags: java, instanceof

I have a listener class which listens to message objects. The messages objects are checked for instance types and appropriate action is taken once instance type is determined. Below is the sample code

```
public void onMessage(IMessage message){

   if(message instanceof MoPn) {
      doThis();
   } else if(message instanceof MoAn) {
      doThat();
   } else if(message instanceof MoBn) {
      doSomethingElse();
   }
}
```

I know this is not the best possible way of doing this, but for legacy reasons, I cant change it. The point now is I wanted to make the message handling asynchronous. All I would like to do is check if the message falls in the category I am interested in. If yes, put it in the Queue for async processing. Below is the sample class.

```
public class SampleClass
{
    List<Class<? extends IMessage>> messageClasses = new ArrayList<Class<? extends IMessage>>();

    SampleClass() {
        messageClasses.add(moAn.class);
        messageClasses.add(moBn.class);
        messageClasses.add(moPn.class);
    }

    public void onMessage(IMessage message) {
        for(IMessage messageClass : messageClasses) {
           if(message instanceof messageClass) {
              putItInTheQueue(message);
           }
        }   
    }
}
```

When I code like the above, I cant cast my message class properly. Can somebody help me writing syntactically correct code for the below statement?

```
 if(message instanceof messageClass  )
```

Comment: The elements of your `messageClasses` list would be `Class` objects, not `IMessage` objects.

Comment: If you do the same thing for every kind of message, why the check in the first place? Or is this just a simplified example?

Answer (score 3):

`instanceof` only works with classes known at compile time. Check the documentation of [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instead. You can do something like:

```
public void onMessage(IMessage message) {
    for(Class<? extends IMessage> messageClass : messageClasses) {
        if(messageClass.isAssignableFrom(message.getClass())) {
            putItInTheQueue(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should be message.getClass(), isAssignableFrom() takes a Class as arguement

Comment: Yes it should, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 parentClazz.isAssignableFrom(clazz)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have mentioned you can use `messageClass.isAssignableFrom(message.getClass())`.

You can also use the [isInstance method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-), which is pretty much the exact equivalent of the `instanceof` operator(with the arguments swapped). I.e.

```
for(Class<? extends IMessage> messageClass : messageClasses) {
    if(messageClass.isInstance(message)) {
        putItInTheQueue(message);
    }
}
```